# Shutdown/reboot/hibernate/logout sequence is not working properly in ubuntu 16.04 with intel graphics

Tags: boot, 16.04, graphics, dell, intel-graphics

Hope you can help me. I bought few days ago the new dell xps 15 and I installed ubuntu. My problem is the shutdown/reboot/hibernate/logout sequence is not working properly when I have enabled the intel graphics, the screen is freezed with an output error. This laptop has a nvidia gtx1050 graphic card and when I have this graphic card enabled with nvidia-prime the  shutdown/reboot/hibernate/logout sequence is working properly. I am searching the solution but for the moment I do not find anything. Can you give me some hints?

My intel processor is:
Intel® Core™ i7-7700HQ

Error output:

```
recovering journal
/dev/nvme0n1p8: clean, xxx/xxx files, xxx/xxx blocks
```

Thanks

Comment: is it not shutting down at all or it's flickering while  shutting down?

Comment: Is not shutting down,  it is freezed with the output error.